# Filtering unit from a list of records : BS4 Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping tables from this [platform](http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels). After retrieving all the information, i store them to a list successfully. Next thing, i want to do is to filter unit (km2) from list containing records.

For example:

Catchment area has measurement as 0.1 km2, i want to remove km2 for all records in that column

The approach i am using is :

```
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import uuid
import csv
import dateutil.parser as parser
import pandas as pd

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


class crawlOcean():

    def __init__(self):
        print("hurray33")
        global downloadDir
        global uFileName
        global filname
        downloadDir = ""
        uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
        filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                          "attachment/csv")
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("hurray")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.driver.get("http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels")
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def crawl(self):
        print("see")
        driver = self.driver
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
        driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_MenuItem_3_text").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="All"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Active EPA/LA (239)"]').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        headers = []
        for m in soup.find_all("th"):
            headers.append(m.get_text())
        print(headers)
        content = []
        finalContent = []
        filterList = ["km²"]
        for table in soup.find_all("table")[5::]:
            for row in table.find_all("tr"):
                contentCells = []
                for cells in row.find_all("td"):
                    if cells.text.split()not in filterList:
                        contentCells.append(cells.text)
                content.append(contentCells)


        print(content)
        with open(filname, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(headers)
            writer.writerows(content)
        driver.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = crawlOcean()
    obj.crawl()
```

Sample Output:

```
['Station number', 'Station name', 'Waterbody', 'Status', 'Type of Gauge', 'Catchment area', 'Data Provider', 'River Basin', 'Timestamp', 'Value', 'Unit']
[['14107', 'BAYLOUGH BR.', 'BARROW', 'Active', 'Recorder', '431.50 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '58.419', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['18118', 'SHANBALLYMORE', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Munster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '0.432', '---'], ['14108', 'BALLYNAFAGH', 'STREAM', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '84.531', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['14104', 'GREESEMOUNT', 'GREESE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '74.60 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 08:00', '90.877', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['14100', 'KYLE SPRING', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '17-10-2018 14:15', '91.595', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['03059', 'DRUMULLY BR.', 'MOUNTAIN WATER', 'Active', 'Staff Gauge Only', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '01-10-2018 12:45', '100.280', 'm (TBM)'], ['03070', 'EMY LOUGH', 'EMY LOUGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '50.884', 'm OD (Poolbeg)'], ['03057', 'EMYVALE WEIR', 'MOUNTAIN WATER', 'Active', 'Recorder', '37.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '52.431', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['18048', 'DROMCUMMER', 'BLACKWATER [MUNSTER]', 'Active', 'Recorder', '867.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Munster)', '25-10-2018 01:00', '60.605', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['14057', 'TIMOLIN', 'BOTHOGUE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '18.20 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '89.953', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['28011', 'DOO LOUGH OUTFLOW', '---', 'Active', 'Recorder', '22.81 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Annageeragh-Annagh-Creegh', '25-10-2018 09:00', '80.743', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07071', 'SKEAGH', 'SKEAGH L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '5.30 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Boyne', '15-08-2018 14:00', '149.503', 'm OD (Poolbeg)'], ['03051', 'FAULKLAND', 'BLACKWATER (MONAGHAN)', 'Active', 'Recorder', '143.20 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '19-09-2018 17:00', '41.572', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07077', 'WHITE LOUGH.', 'ANNAGH OR WHITE LOUGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Boyne', '05-09-2018 13:30', '105.169', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['10038', 'DRUIDS GLEN', 'STREAM', 'Active', 'Recorder', '16.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Potters-Redcross-Three Mile Water', '25-10-2018 09:00', '19.377', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['36031', 'LISDARN', 'CAVAN', 'Active', 'Recorder', '63.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Erne', '25-10-2018 09:00', '52.317', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07074', 'BALLANY', 'LENE L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '13.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Boyne', '25-10-2018 09:00', '92.667', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['16047', 'CARROWCLOGH', 'ARA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '44.10 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Suir', '25-10-2018 08:00', '80.820', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['30012', 'CLAREGALWAY', 'CLARE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '1072.90 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Corrib', '24-10-2018 20:30', '6.355', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['16045', 'BALLYSHONOCK RESRVR.', 'DAWN', 'Active', 'Recorder', '5.20 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Suir', '09-08-2018 13:15', '89.683', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07078', 'LOUGH BANE', 'BANE L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '', 'Environmental Protection Agency', '---', '25-10-2018 09:00', '111.051', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['10028', 'KNOCKNAMOHILL', 'AUGHRIM', 'Active', 'Recorder', '203.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Avoca', '24-10-2018 20:00', '21.322', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['29071', 'CUTRA', 'L.    CUTRA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '123.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Kinvarra', '25-10-2018 08:15', '32.694', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['25070', 'WHITEBRIDGE.', 'L.ENNELL', 'Active', 'Recorder', '147.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '78.934', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['29018', 'CLARINBRIDGE SPRING', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Kilcogan', '27-09-2018 12:30', '2.926', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['25072', 'CAPTAIN S HILL', 'OWEL L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '22.60 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '96.146', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['10021', 'COMMON S ROAD', 'SHANGANAGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '32.50 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Loughlinstown', '25-10-2018 08:00', '10.806', 'm OD (Poolbeg)'], ['26204', 'BALLYMARTIN', 'HIND', 'Active', 'Recorder', '44.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '40.009', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['33001', 'GLENAMOY', 'GLENAMOY', 'Active', 'Recorder', '76.10 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Glenamoy-Ballinglen-Glencullen', '25-10-2018 09:00', '3.901', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['22031', 'KILLARNEY SW (New)', 'L. LEANE TRIB', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.06 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Laune', '21-08-2018 11:15', '19.570', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['32076', 'DOO LOUGH', 'DOO LOUGH [MAYO]', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Owenglin-Dawros-Culin-Traheen', '03-09-2018 11:30', '30.237', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['32073', 'LETTERETTRIM', 'L.    FEE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '15.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Carrownisky-Owenwee-Carrowbeg', '25-10-2018 09:00', '44.589', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['32070', 'L.FEEAGH', 'L.    FEEAGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '84.30 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Srahmore', '25-10-2018 09:00', '10.852', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['32026', 'BUNDORRAGHA', 'BUNDORRAGHA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '48.30 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Owenglin-Dawros-Culin-Traheen', '25-10-2018 09:00', '3.358', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['25046', 'LISMOYNY', 'BROSNA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '304.50 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '57.021', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['35073', 'L.GILL', 'L.GILL', 'Active', 'Recorder', '362.60 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Garvogue', '25-10-2018 09:00', '3.823', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['25044', 'COOLE', 'KILMASTULLA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '92.54 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 08:15', '29.649', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['35072', 'TRASGARVE', 'L.    EASKY', 'Active', 'Recorder', '10.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Easky-Dunneil', '06-09-2018 10:45', '183.646', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)']
```

Any one help me follow right approach?

Comment: You want to get all elements in list that ends with `" km²"` or you want to remove `" km²"` from each element? What is your desired output?

Comment: @Andersson i want to remove `km²` which means `431.50 km²` should look like this `431.50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, i have solved it with following approach,

```
filtter = ['km²']
        for table in soup.find_all("table")[5::]:
            for row in table.find_all("tr"):
                contentCells = []
                for cells in row.find_all("td"):
                    contentCells.append(cells.get_text())
            content.append(contentCells)
        for idx, v in enumerate(content):
            for t in filtter:
                content[idx] = [i.replace(t, '') for i in content[idx]]
                #.append(timerecorded)
        print(content)
```

Comment: There is no need in filtering final list with extra loops - you can get `contentCells` list of required elements on the fly with the single line...

Answer (score 1):

you want to remove de Km2 string but keep the value? in that case you should:

```
# just before you append the row
contentCells[5] = re.sub("[^0-9.,]", "", contentCells[5])
content.append(contentCells)
```

or if you want to skip that column:

```
# remove column before add the row
del contentCells[5]

# or filter 

filterList = {"km²"} # create a set with all words
for table in soup.find_all("table")[5::]:
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        contentCells = []
        for cells in row.find_all("td"):
            # create a new set with the cells text, 
            # and intersect with the filter set, if the cell doesn't 
            # contains any filtered text word, it will return an empty set  
            if not set(cells.text.split()).intersection(filterList):
                contentCells.append(cells.text)
        content.append(contentCells)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got list of strings and some of them ends with, e.g.

```
my_list = ['14107', 'BAYLOUGH BR.', '25-10-2018 09:00', '58.419', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)', '0.00 km²']
```

You can try

```
my_list = [item for item in my_list if not item.endswith(" km²")]
```

to get rid of elements that ends with`" km²"`

*Update*

If you want to remove `" km²"` part from elements, try:

```
my_list = [item.rstrip(" km²") for item in my_list]
```

In your case it might be

```
contentCells = [cell.text.rstrip(" km²") for cell in row.find_all("td") if cell.text.strip()]
```

Comment: i get error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` with the above approach

Comment: @NorthernShadow , I guess I forgot to add `text` property or something... Try updated

Comment: thanks, your approach is better interms of efficiency. there is another post i created, please check if you can help